# How to tell if a user clicked on a confirmation email sent with user.sendEmailVerification() in jsx

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, reactjs, jsx

I have this code for send a email,
but I do not know how to wait for the answer (if confirm or not)
because no matter if it confirms or not, it registers it

```
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault()
firebaseAuth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email.value, this.pw.value)
.then(function(user) {
    user.sendEmailVerification()
}).then(function () {
    alert("User signup success");
}).catch(function (error) {
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {

          alert('Wrong password.');
      }
  else if(errorCode=='auth/email-already-in-use'){
    alert("esa cuenta de correo ya esta en uso");
  }
  else {
          alert(errorMessage);
        }
        console.log(error);
      });
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about reactjs or fire base. But what you need to do is before you send the email create a unique id for every user when the submit the sign up form. In the email you genarate you need to add a button(link) to click if user need to get registered to the site. that link should redirect to your site with the id you have saved 
ex
https://yoursite.com/signup-action?id=QSE$#@$WDVVDsfdsfew543

now when user click this you can get the id from the url and check if it is in the database and who is the user and can update the table to activate the user. That is how you know that the user has clicked the email.. then ask the user to log in

Comment: I already have all that, I just need to wait for the response of the user when clicked the link in the mail, but there is no way to take it

Comment: That is what i have explained. once user redirect to the page you want  by clicking the url in the mail you can capture the id from the url. you will get that exact id only if user clicked on the link